# OS X UDP send error: 55 No buffer space available

Tags: python, c, linux, macos, sockets

While I was implementing RUDP in python3.3 on OSX10.9.1 I noticed that the following code actually does not do what it does on linux: (it doesn't matter which language, same behavior for C, Java and C#/Mono)

```
from socket import *

udp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
udp.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, True)

udp.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1337))
udp.setblocking(False)
udp.setsockopt(SOL_IP, IP_TTL, 4)
udp.connect(('8.8.8.8', 12345))

buf = b'x' * 400
for _ in range(1024 * 1024 * 10):
    udp.send(buf)
```

This code just keep writing a lot udp packets to 8.8.8.8, those packets get dropped after 4 hops so they should not reach the destination, it's just to simulate outgoing traffic.

**The problem:**

This code throws an OSError(55, 'No buffer space available') error, while on Linux(Windows, too) it throws a BlockingIOError, which is fine, because it's a nonblocking socket.

So while on linux and windows the socket behaves correctly on OSX this is a OSError, which is bad.

But the really interesting thing is that even if I put this socket into blocking mode, this code does still throw an error on OSX. While on linux and windows this throws no error at all, as expected, it just blocks.

Is this an implementation detail of BSD based systems ? Or am I missing some important network settings ?

[EDIT]

I forgot to mention that I was testing this behavior in a gigabit lan. And I think that was the problem. I connected to a 100mbit network and the problem was gone, even with 300mbit wlan the problem did not occur.

Now I think this is some OSX specific behavior when connected to high speed networks.

[EDIT - FINAL]
I finally found the reason:

http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2004-January/005369.html

On BSD systems sendto NEVER blocks, the docs are wrong. Mixed with some OSX specific problem when connected to high speed lans. Overall: Just don't think that sendto blocks, it doesn't on BSD. The good thing: If you know that, you can take this into account.

Comment: FWIW I've seen the same behavior when doing C-based UDP socket programming on the Mac.  I modified my code to treat it as a transient error (and just try the send() again when it occurs), i.e. same as way it treats EINTR, and that seems to work okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you mean to bind the socket. That should only be done on the server side that you are planning to listen to. What happens if you drop the call to bind? eg:

```
from socket import *
import time

udp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

buf = b'x' * 400
for _ in range(1024 * 1024 * 10):
    while True
        try:
            udp.sendto(buf, ('8.8.8.8', 12345))
            break
        except OSError, exc:
            if exc.errno == 55:
                time.sleep(0.1)
            else:
                raise
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but unfortunately the same behavior.

Comment: I fixated on the wrong element of your post. While you certainly do NOT want to use the bind() call....you also cannot use send() when working with udp. Accoding to the docs, send() is only available for connected sockets (ie: TCP). You need to use sendto(). I've edited my answer to reflect the correct code.

Comment: Well, actually send is totally fine, if you connect. Connect on udp is of course just an alias for sendto. If you use connect, you can use send. It's part of the official bsd socket library. But fair enough, the sendto solution actually is "better" because the exception occurs after writing larger packets (it starts throwing the exception after changing the size from 400 to 900)

Comment: Hmm..I checked the man on unix, and your right. I then checked the source code of the python socketmodule.c (to confirm it wasn't doing anything goofey), and it all looks pretty straightforward. I then did some googling on error 55 from udp write, and stumbled across some interesting details. The short story is that you may be writing packets faster then they can be sent.  Check out this link -- http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/UDP-write-error-55-when-sending-video-over-network/td-p/746327. I've modified example to fold in suggestions.

Comment: Exactly, well, in theory a blocking socket should never throw an exception, it should just block. A nonblocking socket might throw an exception because, as you said, the queue is full. But a nonblocking socket should throw a BlockIOException in Python or should return EWOULDBLOCK in C. I really appreciate your help, btw. But I honestly think that the problem is deeply integrated into the Darwin Kernel. Btw.: I found forum thread earlier this day, and all I can learn from this thread is: Use a 1ms sleep, which is really ugly.

Comment: I didn't down vote anything here. The updated version is actually pretty useful. But I solved this now by registering the socket handle for writable-events instead of sleeping for a given time.

Comment: Thanks.  BTW -- would you mind sharing your solution? I'd be interested in seeing how you registered the socket handler. Does that mean you used select()?

Comment: After one night without sleep I finally found the reason. While select worked at first for me that was not reliable at all. Sometimes the socket was writable for the whole time, no matter how much I wrote (which caused the same problem obviously)but sometimes the socket was not writable (as expected). I used the python-tulip module and the included selectors. But really, it didn't work. I'll update my question, I found out that this is really as BSD issue. You can check the source there.

Answer (score -1):

I was also able to isolate this OSX problem as you can see in this related SO question: [Non-blocking DatagramChannel throws SocketException ("No buffer space available") on OSX but UDP packet is still successfully sent in full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078140/non-blocking-datagramchannel-throws-socketexception-no-buffer-space-available)

It feels like a bug.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)